# Javascript - How to filter an array of Objects by a Parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable which is an array of comments.

```
$scope.numOfCommentsCoupon
```

What i would like to have is a variable which is a count of the Comments inside the array that have a "`couponId`" of a certain value.

Here is the Comment Model

```
    var CommentSchema = new Schema({

    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    couponId: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }

});
```

So i need to filter it and then count it but im not sure how to.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Read [ask] for instructions how to fix that.

Comment: @Ian $scope.numOfCommentsCoupon. thats the array returned from the server function. i need to filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of comments, to do that, you could do something like this

```
var count = 0;
comments.filter(function(comment,index,array){
    if (comment.couponId === "some_value") {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Or you could just iterate over it using the for loop. Pretty straightforward stuff to implement

Answer (score 0):

I think I follow what you're trying to do and you can use `array.filter`

It would look like this:

```
var currentCouponId = 1;
var matching = yourArray.filter(function (element) { return element.couponId == 1; });
console.log(matching.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Youd could use `reduce` method on the array to get the count of coupons whose `couponId` is equals to a given string:

```
var comments = [
    {
        couponId : "1"
    },
    {
        couponId : "2"
    }
];

var couponIdToCount = "2";

var count = comments.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return current.couponId == couponIdToCount ? previous + 1: previous;
}, 0);

console.log(count)
```